# Анимация CheckBox элемента в XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой анимации "галочки" в CheckBox.

Задача: должна прорисовываться постепенно. Именно рисоваться, так что вариант с прозрачностью не подходит.

Сам элемент определен следующим кодом:

```
 <Path x:Name="optionMarkNew" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="Red" Margin="1" Opacity="1" Stretch="Fill" Width="12" Height="10"/>
```

Пробовал сделать через PointAnimationUsingPath, но ничего не получается.

Мой код, который переделал в попытках понять, как это работает. Получаю ошибку по TargetProperty, но кажется, что вообще в попытках разобраться зашел совсем не в ту сторону.

```
 <Path x:Name="New" Fill="Green" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="18" Stretch="Fill" Width="22">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry x:Name="Figure">
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="9.97498,1.22334">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>                                    
                                    
                                    <LineSegment Point="4.52164,9.09834"/>
                                    <LineSegment Point="0,5.19331"/>
                                    <LineSegment Point="1.27664,3.52165"/>
                                    <LineSegment Point="4.255,6.08833"/>
                                    <LineSegment Point="8.33331,1.52588e-005"/>
                                    
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
        <Path.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="MyStory">
                    <Storyboard>                          
                        <PointAnimationUsingPath
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Figure"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point"
                            Duration="0:0:10" 
                             RepeatBehavior="Forever" >
                            <PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                <PathGeometry Figures="M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334"/>
                            </PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                        </PointAnimationUsingPath>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Path.Triggers>
    </Path>
```

Буду благодарен за подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

Ниже я сделал анимацию для вашей проблемы, вам нужно поиграть с `BeginTime` и `Duration`для каждого сегмента если хотите сделать другой порядок.

```
<Path x:Name="New"
          Fill="Transparent"
          Stroke="Green"
          StrokeThickness="2"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          Height="18"
          Stretch="Fill"
          Width="22">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry x:Name="Figure">
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure IsClosed="True"
                                    StartPoint="9.97498,1.22334">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <LineSegment x:Name="LineSegment1"
                                                 Point="0,0" />
                                    <LineSegment x:Name="LineSegment2"
                                                 Point="0,0" />
                                    <LineSegment x:Name="LineSegment3"
                                                 Point="0,0" />
                                    <LineSegment x:Name="LineSegment4"
                                                 Point="0,0" />
                                    <LineSegment x:Name="LineSegment5"
                                                 Point="0,0" />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
        <Path.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="MyStory">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineSegment1"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point"
                                        From="0,0"
                                        To="4.52164,9.09834"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineSegment2"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point"
                                        From="0,0"
                                        To="0,5.19331"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineSegment3"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point"
                                        From="0,0"
                                        To="1.27664,3.52165"
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineSegment4"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point"
                                        From="0,0"
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                        To="4.255,6.08833"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineSegment5"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point"
                                        From="0,0"
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                        To="8.33331,1.52588e-005"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Path.Triggers>
    </Path>
```